# When I empty datatable I get 2 thead

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a table that I fill with the jQuery `.append()`, subsequently I declare It like datatable. Since is not an ajax call that fill the table, I use `.empty()` to clear the `tbody` and `thead`, the problem comes here:

`tbody` has been cleared and replaced with new datas but the `thead` is double (one in dataTables_scrollHead with the new info, one as thead of the table in dataTables_scrollBody with old info). The one inside dataTables_scrollBody disappears when I resize the page or I open the console. After this, the table return normal with just one thead, but every time that i repeat this actions without change the size one more thead is added inside the table of dataTables_scrollBody.

Here my code:

```
$("#table tbody").empty();
$("#table thead").empty();
dataTableTest = $("#table");

var h="<tr>";
for(var i=0;i<data.info.length;i++)                 
    h+="<th style='cursor:pointer;'>"+hello+"</th>";
dataTableTest.find("thead").append(h+"</tr>");

h="";
for(var i=0;i<data.list.length;i++) {
    h+="<tr>";
    for(var j=0;j<data.list[i].length;j++)
        h+="<td>"+data.list[i][j]+"</td>";
    h+="</tr>"
}
dataTableTest.find("tbody").append(h);

dataTableTest.DataTable({
                        "scrollY": "367px",
                        "scrollX": true,
                        "bSort": false,
                        "orderMulti": false,
                        "searching": false,
                        "paging": false,
                        "bInfo": false,
                        "language": {
                            "emptyTable": NORECORD
                           }
                    });
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, to reset the table I just do this:

```
if ( $.fn.DataTable.isDataTable('#table_id') ) {
    $('#table_id').DataTable().clear().destroy();
}
$('#table_id').empty();
```

I hope this could help you.

Answer (score -1):

You're using append, which appends the contents in the specified container.

```
dataTableTest.find("thead").append(h+"</tr>");
```

Instead of appending, you can directly use .replaceWith() to replace the tag with the new one.

```
$("#table thead").replaceWith(h+"</tr>");
```

Comment: I have tried but your suggestion doesn't work, I got the same result